# Connecting to a TcpListener on a different thread, same process

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm trying to unit test some comm. code over TCP in C#.  I've created a quick thread that stands up a TcpListener.  Each time the TcpClient tries to connect I get an "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted" exception.  Can you not host on and connect to the same port in the same process?

```
    [Test]
    public void Foo()
    {
        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(TcpListenerThread);

        listenerThread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234));        
    }

    private void TcpListenerThread()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient socket = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(socket.GetStream());

        writer.Write(File.ReadAllBytes("../../random file.txt"));

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong constructor of the [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1612451t%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) - this one binds the client to **local address and port**, so you end up with both the listener and the client trying to grab `127.0.0.1:1234`. Use the [`TcpClient( String, int )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329758%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) constructor.

Comment: Or the empty TcpClient ctor and use the TcpClient.Connect method